# Filter words having dots and ending with square braces

Tags: java, regex

To keep it simple, lets take following example:

```
iphone Foo.bar.StartTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15] and apple Bar.Foo.BarTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15] apple
```

from above text I wanted to filter `Foo.bar.StartTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15]` and `Bar.Foo.BarTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15]` using regex. there can be any combinations instead of `Bar.Foo.BarTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15]` but it will be in same format.

I tried this `(?<!\\S)[][^[]]*` regex but its only filtering text surrounded by Square brackets.

How should I frame the regex to get the desired result?

here is link to regex101.com: https://www.regex101.com/r/QLP4jB/1

Comment: Should `StartTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15]` also be filtered ?

Comment: Yes. regex should filter it too.

Comment: Then my regex treat that case :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\w+(\.\w+)*:\[[^]]*\]
```

[**Regex Tester.**](https://www.regex101.com/r/QPDCWF/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex without any lookaround:

```
(?:\w+\.)+\w+:\[[^]]+\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/QLP4jB/2)

**Java Code**

```
final String regex = "(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w+:\\[[^]]+\\]";
final String string = "iphone Foo.bar.StartTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15] and apple Bar.Foo.BarTimestamp:[2012-11-12 TO 2016-02-15] apple";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```